# Can Entity Framework be used to partially map an existing database?

Tags: entity-framework-6

Just getting started with EF v6 and trying to see if I can retrofit it to an existing database. In some ways it looks like the existing database will map well to an object model (HealthProviders, Patients, Visits) however in other ways some of the tables won't map easily to objects. That being said does EF require mapping all database objects to code or can you pick and choose which database objects are modeled in EF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Using database first - the default - you get to choose which objects - tables, views, stored procedures - you want to map.